# Calling a class's constant in another class's variable

Tags: php, class, variables, static, constants

I was wondering if there is any possibility in PHP to do following;

```
<?php

class boo {
 static public $myVariable;

 public function __construct ($variable) {
   self::$myVariable = $variable;
 }
}

class foo {
  public $firstVar;
  public $secondVar;
  public $anotherClass;

 public function __construct($configArray) {
   $this->firstVar = $configArray['firstVal'];
   $this->secondVar= $configArray['secondVar'];
   $this->anotherClass= new boo($configArray['thirdVal']);
 }
}

$classFoo = new foo (array('firstVal'=>'1st Value', 'secondVar'=>'2nd Value', 'thirdVal'=>'Hello World',));

echo $classFoo->anotherClass::$myVariable;
?>
```

**Expected OUTPUT :** `Hello World`

I am getting following error; `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`

I Googled and it is related to **colon (double dots)** in `$classFoo->anotherClass::$myVariable`

I wouldn't like to go all the trouble to change my other classes. Is there anyway around this problem?

Thank you for your help in advance.

**P.S.** I just didn't want to lose few hours on this to find a way around. I already spent yesterday 2.5 hours to change almost whole Jquery because customer wanted a change and today in the morning I was asked to take the changes back because they didn't want to use it (they changed their mind). I am just trying to avoid big changes right now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to do:

```
$anotherClass = $classFoo->anotherClass;
echo $anotherClass::$myVariable;
```

Expanding expressions to class names/objects for static calls/constants is not supported (but expanding variables, as shown above, is).

Comment: I don't know, why I haven't tried this one (: Thanks a lot for your help. Need to wait a bit more to accept your answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's [still not valid](http://www.ideone.com/6Vo17), unless it's new to PHP? _EDIT:_ Also, what about using `${...}` to eval a `get_class` result?

Comment: @Brad Christie: It's valid in 5.3.

Comment: @Brad Christie: What do you mean "eval a get_class result"?

Comment: @netcoder: When i think static I think to reference the name of the class, not the instance of the class being implemented in a static format (as 5.3 appears to do). I was having trouble getting `$anotherClass::$myVariable` to work, so instinctively I though to use `get_class` (basically emulate "boo::$myVariable", where boo would be `get_class($classFoo->anotherClass)`) but now I see there's no need. Long story short, I was trying to work around a problem that i didn't know didn't exist. ;p

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about memory and execution speed, this is correct.
It seems that reference would be better:

```
$classRef = &$classFoo->anotherClass;
echo $classRef;
```

Works for me.